# Auth0 angular 7 login redirect loop

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7, auth0

I am using auth0 to configure my angular 7 app with auth. I followed the quickstart guide to get up and running.  The only thing I added in addition to the auth.service.ts file is:

```
  getTokenSilently$(options?): Observable<string> {
    return this.auth0Client$.pipe(
      concatMap((client: Auth0Client) => from(client.getTokenSilently(options)))
    );
  }
```

to support the HTTP interceptor:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class InterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private auth: AuthService) { }

  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return this.auth.getTokenSilently$().pipe(
      mergeMap(token => {
        const tokenReq = req.clone({
          setHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
        });
        return next.handle(tokenReq);
      }),
      catchError(err => throwError(err))
    )
  }
}
```

The other thing I did differently is that my app does not have a login button, when the app starts up it trys to go to the home page which has an auth guard:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private auth: AuthService) {}

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean|UrlTree> | boolean {
    return this.auth.isAuthenticated$.pipe(
      tap(loggedIn => {
        if (!loggedIn) {
          this.auth.login(state.url);
        }
      })
    );
  }

}
```

so it automatically calls the login so the user gets redirected to auth0.  Once they enter their creds it then redirects them back to the home page.  Then all of a sudden the auth.service.ts service is loaded again and the auth guard has fired again and it fires the login function again.  This seems to just keep on looping.

Any idea why it just keeps on looping?

Comment: Also I should mention this is running on S3 so not sure if that matters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace your Guard method by this one :

```
    canActivate(
        next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot
    ): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean {
        return this.auth.isAuthenticated$.pipe(
            delay(1000),
            tap(loggedIn => {
                if (!loggedIn) {
                    this.auth.login(state.url);
                }
            })
        );
    }
```

The problem was that `loggedIn` is still at `false`, even after a successful login.
I am aware that this is not a clean or pretty solution. 
I modestly think that the **Auth0 Angular** sample needs some fixes.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** This answer could be helpful to avoid the redirect loop issue for anyone building a Angular SPA

1. And using the auth0 angular SDK's inbuilt AuthGuard
2. Or/And using the auth0 provided login page with callback URL
3. Or facing auth.isAuthenticated$ is always false issue

Try setting the **'Application Type'** to **'Single Page Application'** in auth0 application properties page
[image]